# Adding a GridLayout to a Document Type in Umbraco 7.6

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I have defined a grid layout as a data type in Umbraco. The version is 7.6.1 and I have the Fanoe starter kit installed.

I want to add this new grid layout data type as a property to a document type.

When I add a new property to the document type, and then choose the grid layout editor, I get the Fanoe row/column options and have no way of choosing my new Grid Layout data type.  How can I add the editor with my new data type?

All of the tutorials say it should be added to the Generic Properties tab, but in this version of Umbraco, the Generic Properties tab is no longer available.

Comment: You can enter your properties in any tab, it doesn't have to be in the Properties tab. I don't really get what you issue is. You have to create a new DataType using the GridLayout property editor. Then create a property using that DataType.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new content grid data type and then add that data type to your document type. See this YouTube video I made, to show you how to do it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTYDvGw7mzE